# Circular Image view in Flutter and select image from external source

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and I need help on this. I want to create a circular image view in Flutter and on clicking the view I want the app to prompt the user to select the image from the mobile device's gallery. Upon selecting the image, the image should be displayed on the image view. Is there any way that this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. You need to show some sample/design first of what you want. Maybe draw something:

However, you can create a circular image with Widget called;

```
CircleAvatar(
              child: Image.network("http://image.com"),
```

),

Then you can wrap it in GestureDetect() Widget and

```
GestureDetector(
Child: CircleAvatar(
                  child: Image.network("http://image.com"),
    ),
onTap: ImagePicker....,)
```

[ImagePicker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) can be used to add the capability of allowing users to upload image from gallery.